# Best way to find treasure maps

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Is there a particular zombie (or loot container) that is more likely to drop treasure maps, or is it just equal probability for all of them?

Comment: If you are on PC go to your game directory the game is installed in and look into the data-config folder. If you open the Loot.xml with notepad or notepad++ you could have a look through there. I don't know what item name the different treasure maps are but searching for treasure might get you a match. Each item is part of a loot group table and each loot group is part of a loot table to different types of loot, such as containers, zombies, etc.. That file should help you see how it is configured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Nope, I found the following probabilities for getting treasure maps for each `lootgroup`:

- junk: 0.092
- generic zombie loot: 0.161
- zombieMaleHazmat: 0.092
- ZombieCheerleader: 0.031
- ZombieSkateboarder: 0.031
- ZombieFootballPlayer: 0.092
- zombieOldTimer / zombieCowboy: 1
- zombieBusinessMan: 0.031

I'm not sure what `zombieOldTimer` is (I thought it might be the generic corpse container, but it looks like `generic zombie loot` already covers that), but the Cowboy is clearly the best zombie to kill if you're after a treasure map.

On my machine, the file is located at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\7 Days To Die\Data\Config\loot.xml`

---

It seems that the cowboy is actually called "zombieOldTimer". Checking in `entitygroups.xml` in the same directory, it seems that he spawns in "old west towns":

```
<entitygroup name="ZombieGhostTownGroup"> <!-- old west town -->
        <entity name="zombieOldTimer" prob="3"/>
        <entity name="zombieMarlene" />
        <entity name="zombieArlene" />
        <entity name="zombieJoe" />
        <entity name="zombieSteveCrawler" />
        <entity name="zombieFemaleFat" />
        <entity name="zombieSkateboarder" />
        <entity name="zombieBoe" />
        <entity name="zombieMoe" />
        <entity name="animalZombieDog" />
        <entity name="zombieFatHawaiian" prob="0.5" />
    </entitygroup>
```

Comment: If you want to know exactly what each Zombie looks like you can use the debug console on PC in a single player game. I think opening the console is F1 or possibly ``` then type `DM` after that ...I think it's F6 to bring up the Zombie Spawning Chart. Look for zombieOldTimer and spawn 1 in :)